# Calculate relative RMSE in r

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistics

To get the relative RMSE of my predicted model and true values,I used the code

```
ratio<-prediction1/ISEtrain  

rRMSE1<-sqrt(mean((1-ratio)^2))
```

but I failed , with the output "[1] Inf". What is wrong with my code?

Thank you !

Comment: any zeroes in `ISEtrain` ?

Comment: yes..several zeros so that means several ratios are infinity? then what should I do instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting `Inf` because you are dividing by zero.

Following Wikipedia's definition of the normalized RMSE (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation), you probably want:

```
sqrt( mean( (prediction1-ISEtrain)^2) ) / ( max(ISEtrain)-min(ISEtrain) )
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to get relative RMSE (or normalized RMSE):

1. Divide RMSE by standard deviation of observed values:

   ```
   sqrt(mean((prediction1 - ISEtrain)^2)) / sd(ISEtrain)
   ```
2. Divide RMSE by difference between max and min of observed values (as David mentioned):

   ```
   sqrt(mean((prediction1 - ISEtrain)^2)) / diff(range(ISEtrain))
   ```

Both methods exist in `"hydroGOF"` package and do exactly the same but proper function name to do so is `nrmse()` not `rmse()` as mentioned previously.

```
library("hydroGOF")

nrmse(prediction1, ISEtrain, norm = "sd")
nrmse(prediction1, ISEtrain, norm = "maxmin")
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes but the calculation of rmse in the hydroGOF package isn't the same as the relative root mean square error, see below:

```
RRMSE = (sqrt(sum(predicted-observed)^2))/ (number of observations * mean of observation)
```

the rmse calculation in HydroGOF is

```
rmse = sqrt (mean((sim-obs)^2, na.rm=TRUE)
```

So unfortunately these calculations are quite different.

I'm unaware at this time of a package containing this function so it may be necessary to create your own.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just RMSE, you can also use built-in functions of the [hydroGOF](https://www.rforge.net/doc/packages/hydroGOF/rmse.html) package, e.g.:

```
rmse(prediction1,ISEtrain, na.rm=TRUE)
```

This function can easily handle NA or missing values setting `na.rm=TRUE`, see documentation for details.

Moreover, package contains other useful Goodness-of-fit functions such as NRMSE, MAE, GOF, etc.